# How to get value from registry on x86 application running on 64bit system via go programming language?

Tags: go, registry

I can't get values from keys in windows registry.
I compile my application with this settings

```
GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build -o test.exe test.go && ./test.exe
```

via go version go1.12.7 windows/amd64
running on 64-bit OS Windows 10

i getting value of key via this code

```
k, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.LOCAL_MACHINE, <my_key_path_variable>, registry.QUERY_VALUE|registry.WOW64_32KEY)
...
value, _, err := k.GetStringValue(`Path`)
```

I successfully getting value from 
*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node*, but when i get key (not value) from *HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE* i'm getting error "The system cannot find the file specified.", but key is 100% exists in registry. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the application with administrator privilege.

1. Open `CMD` as Administrator
2. Go to your project folder, then run the application

Comment: Thanks for answer, but this not helped